# How to change the tooltip text dynamically in cognos charts

Tags: javascript, cognos, cognos-8

I have an issue in cognos chart , I have placed a data item in the chart series and name it criteria.

The data item contains a case statement

when (Metrics = 7) then ([Ace])

when (Metrics = 5) then ([Effort])

when (Metrics = 9) then ([Defect])

so when my parameter value is 7 the tooltip should show "Ace"  ,
when its 5 the tooltip should show "effort"

how to achieve this in cognos chart series?